# AutoMapper map to derived class based on condition

Tags: automapper

I want to map a base class to one of several derived classes based on a property value in the source. So far I have this, but it seems a bit unwieldy and ugly. Is there a better way?

```
Mapper.CreateMap<DTO.BaseData, BaseData>()
                .ConstructUsing(src =>
                {
                    switch (src.Type)
                    {
                        case 0:
                            return new FtpData(src.Id, src.Content);

                        // many more case statements in here.....

                    }

                    return new NullData();
                });
```